# How to import Angular Material in project?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have installed Angular Material Design. Now I try to add this in `app.module.ts` file:

```typescript
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

What I should decify in section: `imports: []`? that to load all material entities.

I tried: `imports: ['MaterialModule']` but it is deprecated

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: I did that, as you can see there is an sample with `import { MaterialModule} from '@angular/material` here

Comment: I dont see that in the page

Comment: Yes, therfore I ask how to import all modules

Comment: Ill add an answer, I think you might be looking at an old, cached documentation page or similar...

Comment: Is there a section of the documentation I'm missing? I'm reading source on github for module names.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

**UPDATE for Angular 9.0.1**

Since this version there is no barrel file for massive exports in the root index.d.ts. The assets imports should be:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

source: [@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503)

---

MaterialModule was depreciated in version 2.0.0-beta.3 and it has been removed completely in version 2.0.0-beta.11. See this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more details. Please go through the breaking changes.

**Breaking changes**

- Angular Material now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater
- **MaterialModule**    has been removed.
- For beta.11, we've made the decision to **deprecate the "md"** prefix
  completely and **use "mat"** moving forward.

Please go through [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) we will get more answer!

Example shown below
cmd

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/animations @angular/cdk
npm install --save angular/material2-builds angular/cdk-builds
```

Create file (material.module.ts) inside the 'app' folder

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

import on app.module.ts

```typescript
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
```

Your component html file

```xml
<div>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span><mat-icon>mood</mat-icon></span>

    <span>Yay, Material in Angular 2!</span>

    <button mat-icon-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-menu x-position="before" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
  </mat-menu>

  <mat-card>
    <button mat-button>All</button>
    <button mat-raised-button>Of</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">The</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Buttons</button>
  </mat-card>

  <span class="done">
    <button mat-fab>
      <mat-icon>check circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Add global css 'style.css'

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Your component css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

mat-card {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

mat-toolbar-row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.done {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

**If any one didn't get output use below instruction**

instead of above interface (material.module.ts) u can directly use below code also in the app.module.ts.

```typescript
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatInputModule,MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
```

So this case u don't want to import

```typescript
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
```

in the app.module.ts

Comment: Great Answer Rijo. & very timely indeed! Got a quick question that bugs me for some time. It's not a big deal but I'm just curious. See the `./` in the `import { MaterialModule } from './material.module'`?  I was told that `./` means the current directory. But why do we need it? Don't we assume that anyway when `/` or `../` is not in use in the path anyway?  An HTML example to this would be that we never do this: <a href='./index2.htm'></a> when hitting the index2.htm from index.htm if both are in the same directory. See what I mean?

Comment: It would be realy nice if there is some kind of automated generator / validator / cleanup for the material-import.module.ts  Ok i understand the how it works, and i have my "version" setup and copy it from project to project, and it has "filled up"  over the time.  But removing unused Modules  (review by hand all templates) is not what i often do.  So the new import has no advantage to the old / deprecated  but complete MaterialModule  ...

Comment: For Angular library, there is no app.module, how about this case?

Answer (score 20):

Import all Angular Material modules in Angular 9.

Create material.module.ts file in your_project/src/app/ directory and paste this code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';


@NgModule( {
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule

    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MatDatepickerModule,
    ]
} )

export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Add just the required modules which is required. Yes to maintain a separate module is good. But just import only the required one's.

Comment: Thanks for this list.  I could not understand why none of the Internet tutorials about Material wouldn't work with Angular 9.1.  After changing them in line with your list, they do now work.

Comment: man, this will work but it is heavy bad practice cause you will load so much unnecessary stuff into your project

Comment: @IonicMan I can't imagine how that few kb of extra js code would affect the performance of your application. If you want to use the entire UI kit, you would include 90% of the modules anyways. So the impact on the bundle size is irrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to import *all* Material modules, create your own module i.e. `material.module.ts` and do something like the following:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as MATERIAL_MODULES from '@angular/material';

export function mapMaterialModules() {
  return Object.keys(MATERIAL_MODULES).filter((k) => {
    let asset = MATERIAL_MODULES[k];
    return typeof asset == 'function'
      && asset.name.startsWith('Mat')
      && asset.name.includes('Module');
  }).map((k) => MATERIAL_MODULES[k]);
}
const modules = mapMaterialModules();

@NgModule({
    imports: modules,
    exports: modules
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Then import the module into your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when compiling with `--prod` option

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: Posted this when I was on Angular 5.2.0, using this package: https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

Answer (score 10):

The `MaterialModule` was deprecated in the **beta3** version with the goal that developers should only import into their applications what they are going to use and thus improve the bundle size.

The developers have now 2 options:

- Create a **custom** `MyMaterialModule` which imports/exports the components that your application requires and can be imported by other (feature) modules in your application.
- Import directly the individual material modules that a module requires into it.

Take the following as example (extracted from [material page](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started))

**First approach:**

```typescript
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  exports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
})
export class MyOwnCustomMaterialModule { }
```

Then you can import this module into any of yours.

**Second approach:**

```typescript
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Now you can use the respective material components in all the components **declared in** `PizzaPartyAppModule`

It is worth mentioning the following:

- With the latest version of material, you need to import
  `BrowserAnimationsModule` into your main module if you want the
  animations to work
- With the latest version developers now need to add `@angular/cdk` to their `package.json` (material dependency)
- Import the material modules always after `BrowserModule`, as stated by the docs:

> Whichever approach you use, be sure to import the Angular Material
>   modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as the import order matters for
>   NgModules.

Comment: How to install this with this webpack? https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Should not they have fixed this first before this breaking change? https://material.angular.io/

Answer (score 7):

Starting from [Angular version 9](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/a1bfc4e2a/CHANGELOG.md#900-next0-cardboard-cpu-2019-10-03):

> Breaking changes:
>
> Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use
>   the individual secondary entry-points, such as
>   @angular/material/button.

This means that:

```js
import { MatInputModule, MatCardModule } from "@angular/material";
```

becomes:

```js
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
import { MatCardModule } from "@angular/material/card";
```

Comment: do you know benefits with individual imports? or what is the reason of this migration

Answer (score 2):

**Install & Add Material to Angular Projects**

There is an automatic/easy way of adding Material to Angular Projects. Use the Angular CLI's install schematic to set up your Angular Material project by running the following command:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

The ng add command will additionally perform the following configurations:

- Add project dependencies to package.json
- Add the Roboto font to your index.html
- Add the Material Design icon font to your index.html
- Add a few global CSS styles to:

  - Remove margins from body
  - Set height: 100% on html and body
  - Set Roboto as the default application font

You're done! Angular Material is now configured to be used in your application.

Read more about this [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material)

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1

```
yarn add @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

> Step 2 - Create a new file( /myApp/src/app/material.module.ts ) that includes all the material UI modules (there is no shortcut, you have to include individual modules one by one)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import {
      MatButtonModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatCardModule
    } from '@angular/material';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatCardModule
      ],
      exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatCardModule
      ]
    })
    export class MaterialModule {}
```

> Step 3 - Import and add that newly created module to your
>   **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module'; // material module imported

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule // MAteria module added
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular CLI 9.1.4 and all i did was just run:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

And all the angular material packages were installed and my package.json file was updated.

This is the easiest way to get that done.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a SharedModule for the essential material components of your app, and then import every single module you need to use into your feature modules. I wrote an article on medium explaining how to import Angular material, check it out:

https://medium.com/@benmohamehdi/how-to-import-angular-material-angular-best-practices-80d3023118de

Answer (score 0):

above all answer, works but the issue is that it's not affected to project so u need to **restart** ur **serve** its work

```
Ctl+c
```

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score -1):

[Click here to see Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDmsk.png)

If you people are getting this error "compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MatIcon' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation"

Please do not import MatIcon from @angular/material.

Just Import below: 
**import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';**

---

How to import Angular Material?

You can run below command.
**ng add @angular/material**