# Angular import module error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I have two module, `ChatModule` and `LibraryModule` and i want to import the `ChatComponent` inside of the `LibraryComponent` but im get this error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

note: the `mat-tab` is from angular material 2.

**ChatModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat.component';
import { RoomsComponent } from './rooms/rooms.component';
import { ChatviewComponent } from './chatview/chatview.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatComponent,
    RoomsComponent,
    ChatviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ChatComponent
  ]
})
export class ChatModule { }
```

**LibraryModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../core/modules/shared.module';
import { LibraryComponent } from './library.component';
import { ChatModule } from '../chat/chat.module';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'library',
    component: LibraryComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LibraryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ChatModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    LibraryComponent
  ]
})
export class LibraryModule { }
```

**ChatComponent.html**

```
<mat-tab-group id="chat-tabs">
  <mat-tab label="Rooms">
    <fuse-rooms></fuse-rooms>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Contacts">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: you have to import the Material module

Comment: All the material design modules are imported on app.module, on the libraryComponent the material component are working just ok.

Comment: import the `SharedModule` in your `ChatModule`

Comment: Yes that make the job. Thanks so much

Comment: No, you need to import the Material module from your ChatModule if you plan on leveraging its components

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/demo-material-module.ts create module which imports and  the material components like AppMaterialModule and include it in shared module or else include that specific material module in shared module

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, importing the ShareModule was the problem, that is module that have all the angular materials modules and components. Thanks so much your help >D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom `MaterialModule` where you can import modules used in your project.

**MaterialModule**

```
// Core
import {
  MatTabsModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule,
  MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule, MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ MatTabsModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule, MatTooltipModule ],
  exports: [ MatTabsModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule, MatTooltipModule ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

And you can import it in your `SharedModule` like this.

**SharedModule**

```
import { MaterialModule } from './your/path/MaterialModule';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
)}
export class SharedModule {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You Should add the material module. Like this

```
import {  MdtabModule } from '@angular/material';
```

I am not sure `MdtabModule` is available in angular material.

I hope this below discussions could help you.

[How to import Angular Material in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166844/how-to-import-angular-material-in-project)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you have a `SharedModule` which exports your used `MatTabsModule`, you should always make sure you import the right modules for your templates.

In short:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatComponent,
    RoomsComponent,
    ChatviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule        
  ],
  exports: [
    ChatComponent
  ]
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

This is under the impression that you have a `SharedModule` at least like this:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatTabsModule,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```