# Angular Component from a shared module not being recognised in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have a shared module that exports material components, reactive forms and other things but when I try to do that I get these kinds of errors:

> If 'mat-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module.

Until now I've been trying but it doesn't fix. How can I solve it?

Below I will show all my modules so you understand what I'm trying to do. My `pages.module` and `auth.module` are the ones that has the components that are trying to use the `shared.module`.

***App module***

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//My imports
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './../app/core/core.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule,
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Material module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
const MaterialComponents = [
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialComponents
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialComponents
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

***Shared module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/shared/material/material.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

***Auth module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
//import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home/home.component';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home-admin/home-admin.component';
//import{ RoutingModule } from 'src/app/modules/routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent,HomeAdminComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

***Pages module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from 'src/app/pages/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { UsersDashboardComponent } from 'src/app/pages/users-dashboard/users-dashboard.component';
import { RoutingAdminModule } from 'src/app/pages/routing-admin.module';
import { RoutingUsersModule } from 'src/app/pages/routing-users.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminDashboardComponent, UsersDashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RoutingAdminModule,
    RoutingUsersModule,
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166844/how-to-import-angular-material-in-project

Comment: import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/shared/material/material.module';
can you share your MaterialModule?
Did you export all modules you need to use? like MatButtonModule, etc

Comment: @ajuni880 No sorry In the past I've done an export of the  material module without problems , my problem now is with using this shared module

Comment: Why are you importing `SharedModule` into the `AuthModule`, instead of into your root `AppModule`? Also it doesn't look like you import `AuthModule` anywhere either.  Try importing `SharedModule` in your `AppModule`

Comment: I import the `SharedModule` into the `AuthModule` because the `AuthModule` use the `MaterialModule` and `ReactiveForms`. This is for homework and it cant be in the  `AppModule` @Narm

Comment: Yes @RobertB. I export all the material components i use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how i solve it

***Import the modules that have imported the shared module into the App  Module***

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//My imports
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
//import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './../app/core/core.module';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { PagesUsersModule } from 'src/app/pages-users/pages-users.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    AuthModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Import the shared module into the Auth Module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home/home.component';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home-admin/home-admin.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent,HomeAdminComponent],
  imports: [
    AuthRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],

})
export class AuthModule { }
```

***Import the shared into the Pages module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from 'src/app/pages/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { RoutingAdminModule } from 'src/app/pages/routing-admin.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminDashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RoutingAdminModule,
  ],

})
export class PagesModule { }
```

***App-routing.module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//My imports
import { HomeComponent } from './auth/home/home.component';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/shared/guards/auth.guard';
import { HomeGuard } from 'src/app/shared/guards/home.guard';
import { AdminGuard } from 'src/app/shared/guards/admin.guard';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: './pages-users/pages-users.module#PagesUsersModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule', canActivate: [HomeGuard] },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[HomeGuard] }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***Shared module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/shared/material/material.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: I can explain it more, but that post was the code i put to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you accidentally nested the array with the Imports array. The way to fix it would be

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...MaterialComponents
  ],
  exports: [
    ...MaterialComponents
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

In your block of code, you are erroneously setting the first element of the imports array to an array you call "MaterialComponents"; **you accidentally created an array within an array.**

The difference between your code and the solution is the spread syntax (the three periods ...)

In this case, the spread syntax essentially just appends the elements of the "MaterialComponents" to the import array, which is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...MaterialComponents
  ],
  exports: [
    ...MaterialComponents
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Or just:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: MaterialComponents,
  exports: MaterialComponents
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: I already have this, what is the difference of this and what I have?

Comment: exports: [  MaterialComponents ]

This is wrong, i think?
it means:
export: [ [ MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, ... ] ]

Comment: Yes I export my `MaterialComponents` as you see in the question i made

Comment: You did `exports: [ MaterialComponents ]`, please remove the brackets

Comment: Thanks but i did just remove it and didn't make any changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209099/discussion-between-robert-b-and-rinzler21).

Comment: An answer with code and no explanation is unlikely to be upvoted very often and more likely to be downvoted.